# Scale content responsively within an absolutely-positioned, responsive outer container

Tags: css, responsive-design, css-position

I have a project that involves having a sidebar that floats over an image. The sidebar is set to `position: absolute` to keep it over the image and to help it scale along with it when the screen size changes.

Here is a codepen that basically recreates what I'm working on: https://codepen.io/gojiHime/pen/JmYqaz

The issue I'm having is with controlling the size of the contents within the `wrapper` container. I want the `preview` div to scale along with the `wrapper` container. Currently, it does not work as expected in that the `preview` div does not start scaling as the width and height change for `wrapper` and for `thumbs-inner`. The `thumbs-inner` div scales correctly for the most part, but the bottom of div is cut off so you can't see the bottom of the scroll bar in smaller screens.

I know I set `overflow: hidden` on `wrapper` but without it the content in `preview` would extend outside of it as the height of `wrapper` changed.

So, I'm looking for ideas on how to fix the aforementioned issues. `wrapper` must stay absolutely positioned and the `thumbs-inner` div needs to have a vertical scrolling feature, so I can't do anything with those. I don't think setting a height makes sense for `wrapper` since it needs to scale responsively in height and width.

EDIT: Not sure how much this will help but this is a screenshot of what the layout of everything should look like: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLFrK.png)

The Kraftmaid logo, full-size thumbnail and the text below it (which are in the `.preview` div in the codepen) have to be visible at all times when changing the screensize.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for, but generally for responsive layouts you would want to avoid fixed dimensions, such as specific widths set in x number of pixels.

This shows your code with responsive layouts for `.wrapper` and `.thumbs-inner` (note that I haven't addressed any content issues within those two divs since I have no idea what your intended layout is):

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZqrZaj

Note that:

- I've switched the two layout divs to use `box-sizing: border-box;` which will allow you to use pixels for margin and padding but still use percentages for width.
- I've removed width from `.wrapper` and switched to percentage based absolute left and right declarations - if you modify these values, the layout should still work.
- I've added borders to make the layout more obvious.

Comment: This is closer to what I want. As for content, everything in the .preview div should be visible at all times (both images and text below). That's they styling that is missing currently.

Comment: Added a screenshot of the intended design for the final product

Comment: To overlay two divs, I would position the preview div at 100% width, then set the sidebar div to use `position: absolute;`. I recommend giving that a try and posting again (or update this post) with your progress.